# Neo4j: change default Browser settings

Tags: neo4j

I want `"Do not use Bolt"` checkbox being checked by default in Neo4j Browser Settings.

Setting `dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=false` doesn't affect this field in browser.

I'm using Neo4j 3.1.4

How can I change Browser Settings default values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now the only solution I found is to change the default settings in `neo4j-browser-<version>.jar`.

To change `useBolt` setting you need to change `useBolt:!0` to `useBolt:!1` in the JavaScript file located in `browser/scripts` folder of jar file.

This solution was tested for neo4j-browser version `2.0.0-M10`.

Or alternatively you can try to clone [neo4j-browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser), make needed changes and build a jar file.

It would be nice to have an ability to change such settings via a configuration file.